# Concerning the number of members of a primitive residue class $\bmod n$ which are their own multiplicative inverses

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am not well versed in group theory (note that I do not attempt to use the symbology of that art), so please bear with me. I am trying to make sense of what I am reading, in particular to understand how many members of a primitive residue class $\bmod n$ are their own multiplicative inverses. If this question is a duplicate, please direct me to a previous answer. I was led into this line of thought by realizing that if $p=6m-1,\ q=6m+1$ are twin primes, then $6m$ is its own multiplicative inverse $\bmod pq$

I know that if $n$ is prime, then $1,(n-1)$ are the only members of the primitive residue class that are their own multiplicative inverses. I know that if $n$ is composite, there are $\phi(n)$ members of a primitive residue class $\bmod n$ (all coprime to $n$), that $1,(n-1)$ are members, and that those elements are their own multiplicative inverses. I understand that for $n=1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$ the primitive residue class is cyclic.

What I have observed (checking by hand positive integers up to $70$, and by hypothesis beyond) is that for cyclic primitive residue classes, it remains the case that $1,(n-1)$ are the only elements that are their own multiplicative inverses. For primitive residue classes that are not cyclic, there are more than $2$ elements that are their own multiplicative inverses, and the number of such elements always appear to be $2^m$. I appreciate that such self-multiplicative inverse elements must come in pairs, as if $a$ is such an element, then $n-a$ is also such an element. That does not explain the apparent circumstance that the number of such elements is $2^m$ rather than $2m$

**My questions are:** 1. Is it true that non-cyclic primitive residue classes always have more than two elements that are their own multiplicative inverses? (As opposed, for example, to having a plurality of sub-cycles.)  2. Why (if it is in fact true) are the number of self-inverses always a power of $2$? Explanatory answers, pointers to online proofs of such facts, or counterexamples (if looking at positive integers up to $70$ was insufficient to reach a valid inference), would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for an odd prime, the number of square roots of $1 \pmod {p^k}$ is exactly 2. You might see what happens with solving $(1+tp)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2} $ to begin, along with $(-1+tp)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2} .$   Next come  $(1+tp^2)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^3} $ and $(-1+tp^2)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^3}.$   For $\pmod 8$ there are four instead of two, you could call them $\pm 1, \pm 3.$  You still get four $\pmod {2^k} $ for higher $k.$  Presence or abscence of a primitive root has no effect on square roots of $1$

Comment: Thus, the number of square roots of $1 \pmod n$  is always a power of two, just multiply the outcomes for the distinct prime factors of $n$

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks very much for that explanation. It helps me a lot.